# Pass class to Kotlin reified method

Tags: java, generics, kotlin

I have an java api which give me as parameter as type: `modelClass: Class<T>` with this parameter I want to call a kotlin reified method : `intance<reified : T>()`.

It's possible to pass my modelClass as parameter? I have no access to the source code of the reified method.

Answer (score 11):

This is not possible. When calling an inline function with a reified type parameter, you need to provide a class which is known at compile time, and references to that class will be substituted directly into the body of the function where the inline function is invoked. Classes which are only known at runtime cannot be handled in that way.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible if you can modify the source of the Kotlin class. You have to delegate the implementation of the inline/reified function to a non-inline one:

```
class Foo {
    inline fun <reified T> myMethod() = myMethod(T::class.java)

    fun <T> myMethod(type: Class<T>) {
        // implementation here
    }
}
```

This is always good practice if you expect your code to be called from Java projects. And even if it's Kotlin-only, this is a good way to go from `inline` to not `inline`, allowing you to actually call private implementation methods from your exposed `inline` method.